# Is it possbile to use more than one property in clCreateCommandQueue in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am working with OpenCL. My tool is not generating kernel statistics when enabled `OUT-OF-ORDER EXEC MODE`. So i decided to use enable profiling in `clCreateCommandQueue` but, later i realize that how to use two properties at the same time? What i have to do now, i want to run in asynchronous(out-of-orderexecution) mode with profiling enable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The properties arg in **clCreateCommandQueue** is a bit field. The properties constants should be OR'ed together:

```
..., CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE | CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, ...
```

Comment: What if someone need synchronous and without profiling? Is zero illegal?